# S3 preauth timeouts seem to be off

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I've done the following in a unit test with the AWS s3 PHP SDK:

```
$url = $s3->get_object_url($bucket, $path, '10 seconds');
echo $url . "\n";
echo time() . "\n";

sleep(20);
$this->assertEquals(403, $this->getUrlHttpCode($url));
```

The assertion fails, as the URL is still accessible even after 20 seconds.  The 'Expires' URL parameter returned by Amazon is correct, but the request still succeeds.

Is this a bug in S3?  Anyone experience this?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon support has told me that this is caused by a difference between my server's time and the S3 server's time.

This actually does make sense now, as my CI server has been up for like months and a time gap is most likely present.  I added a cronjob to run ntpdate, and my tests seem to be working now.